# When using react-dnd, how can I specify the DragPreviewImage's HTML properties?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

Starting with the [Chessboard Example](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/tutorial) example, the `Knight` component is decalred as

```
export const Knight = () => {
    const [{ isDragging }, drag, preview] = useDrag(() => ({
        type: ItemTypes.KNIGHT,
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
        }),
    }), []);
    return (<>
            <DragPreviewImage connect={preview} src={knightImage}/>
            <div ref={drag} style={{
            ...knightStyle,
            opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
        }}>
                ♘
            </div>
        </>);
};
```

However the image is larger than the board squares. How would I go and resize that preview image for that example **without resizing the source image iteslf**?

Comment: hello, have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that project! I did not, no. I might revisit one day, but if this question becomes inactive, without a working answer, it should be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to customize the preview image myself and found this question.

I've seen that react-dnds recomendation is to create a custom drag layer therefore I tried out https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dnd-preview and it works great!